# Income tax relief on existing home loans for NRI

Tags: united-states, india, non-resident, home-loan, income-tax-refund

I have a rather (IMO) complicated situation, I'd like some clarification on a few points

(Note: all dates, names and numbers below are fictional, just made up to clarify the situation)

1. India, Sep/2015:

   - Salaried and working in India
   - I take a home mortage loan for 20L rupees, floating rate, payable over 120 months
   - I start the construction work on my house
   - 2 joint owners (one is me) and the loan is taken by both owners
   - Other owner has no income
   - My name is not the first name on the borrower list (this seems to matter for some reason)
2. India, Oct/2015

   - I start making EMI payments
   - Construction on going
3. India, Mid Apr/2016

   - I get and accept an offer from a US company
   - I relocate to the US after resigning from Indian company
   - I continue making EMI payments
   - Construction still on going on
   - I file IT returns for the monies earned during the financial year 2015-2016
   - I cant claim any benefit/relief on interest paid/principal amount (80C) as 
     the construction work is still incomplete
4. US, Jun/2016

   - Construction still on going on, seems to take forever
   - I start remitting some money every month to my Indian bank account to keep the 
     requisite funds to pay the EMI as well as keep the work going
5. US, Dec/2016

   - After multiple unavoidables delays, construction still on going on
   - I am still remitting money to India
6. India, Jan/2017

   - Construction almost done, expected to completed by Feb/2017
   - No or very little salary/income from interest on deposits
   - TDS already deducted throughout the year
   - Net income in India < exemption limit according to IT slabs

Some additional notes

- I will be filing my IT returns every year irrespective of income
- It is my understanding that the IT relief on interest paid can be claimed 
  over a period of 5 years in equal installments (20% each year) AFTER the 
  completion of the house but NOT before that.
- As my total income in India is already in the lowest tax bracket (0%) 
  it automatically means I can get a complete refund of all the TDS and income tax.

So my questions are:

1. Can I claim a 20% of the interest paid over the period of Oct/2015 through Mar/2017 (18 months) when I file for IT returns this year in Mar/2017?
2. Does my name not being the first name affect my eligibility of claiming the relief?
3. Does that mean I my claiming the 20% relief on interest (and the remaining 80% over subsequent years) is in effect moot as my "taxable" income cannot go negative (meaning the govt cannot/will not return some money I have paid as IT in prior years)?
4. Does that mean as long as I continue to work in the US (already having become a NRI), have little or no income in India, I cannot claim any future relief regarding the principal or interest?

First post here, Please be considerate before hitting the down vote button if you feel the need to. Please leave a comment so that I can improve the question if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I claim a 20% of the interest paid over the period of Oct/2015 through Mar/2017 (18 months) when I file for IT returns this year in Mar/2017?

Yes you can.

> Does my name not being the first name affect my eligibility of claiming the relief?

No you can claim relief. Joint owners need to file a declaration on the quantum of relief claimed. Both can't claim 100%.

> Does that mean I my claiming the 20% relief on interest (and the remaining 80% over subsequent years) is in effect moot as my "taxable" income cannot go negative (meaning the govt cannot/will not return some money I have paid as IT in prior years)?

If you have no other income on which tax is payable; then Yes it is irrelevant.

> Does that mean as long as I continue to work in the US (already having become a NRI), have little or no income in India, I cannot claim any future relief regarding the principal or interest?

Yes that is right.